# How to increase the spaces between the stars in the custom rating bar in android?

Tags: android, xml, layout, ratingbar

I have designed the custom rating bar in android with different drawable images. I would like to increase the spaces between the stars in the rating bar. 
I know there's a similar question with the same title., in which they've used a third party SDK to create spaces., But it doesn't worked out., Kindly do let me know how can I proceed further.

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RatingBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
        style="@style/ImageRatingBar"
        android:id="@+id/rate"
        android:stepSize="1"
        android:numStars="5"

        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"/>
</LinearLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In my styles.xml:

```
<style name="ImageRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/ratingbar_selector</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">30dp</item>

    </style>
```

In my drawables, the rating_bar_selector.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >


    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/grey_star" />
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/yellow_star" />
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/yellow_star" />

</layer-list>
```

Comment: You can set transparent padding surrounding your icon by using android asset studio.

Comment: @ChiragSolankI.. Yes bro I have tried that.., But the image is not uploaded and viewing properly in that site. This is what the site I have tried:

https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html

Comment: @ChiragSolankI., When I select and upload image it's just showing only white square and the image I upload is not visible

Comment: @ChiragSolankI.. It's done

Comment: what's the problem?

Comment: @ChiragSolankI I've contacted my UI Designer and i got the required image., and the issue has been resolved